# Is there an tutorial that shows how attribute validation works in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'd like to play around with attribute value validation, but the documentation is pretty empty on this. Maybe there's an good article or tutorial out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fairly common validation to ensure you don't get nonsensical dates put into a timeStamp.

```
- (BOOL)validateTimeStamp:(id *)valueRef error:(NSError **)outError 
{
    NSDate *testDate=(NSDate *) valueRef;
    if ([testDate compare:self.minimumTimeStamp]==NSOrderedAscending) {
        // generate and return error so you can set a proper date
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is Core Data calling this validator automatically, or would I have to call that manually before trying to set the value?

Comment: If the method exist in with the proper name, it is called automatically upon an attempt to save the context. I usually prefer to manually call validate at the time the attribute is set so it can be corrected immediately. That is not always feasible.